# Background Button Color is not working properly MACOS

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button, background-color

I am trying to make a simple GUI for a school project. I am new to using tkinter. I used to create my GUIs using pygame, which is great for custumization, but not really for efficiency haha.

I am creating a button for each file in my /graphs folder. In this code, line 42, it seems to me I can't change the background color of the button. This is a reccurent problemI have with tkinter. I have no idea if it is something I am doing wrong or if there is a problem with the framework I am using.

I am trying to make the bg color red.

I am using MACOS, and i know there are complications with tkinter and mac, but i can't use tkmacosx because i need this project to be runnable on windows and linux as well.

Thank you for your help, don't hesitate if you have any suggestions on common practices with tkinter that i am not applying or if you have the solution to my problem !

Here is the output and the code
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmK9f.png)

```py
import tkinter as tk
import os

# colors
SILVER = "#BFACAA"
BLACK = "#02020A"
OXFORD_BLUE = "#05204A"
WISTERIA = "#B497D6"
LAVENDER = "#E1E2EF"
RED = "#FF0000"

# Sizes
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

# Path
PRJ_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("Graph Scheduler")
        self.window.geometry(f"{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}")
        self.window.configure(background=LAVENDER)

        # Title and title box
        title_box = tk.Frame(self.window, bg=SILVER, width=WIDTH)
        title_box.pack(fill="x")
        title = tk.Label(title_box, text="Graph Scheduler", font=("Arial", 40), bg=SILVER, fg=BLACK)
        title.pack(pady=5)

        # File bar
        file_bar = tk.Frame(self.window, bg=OXFORD_BLUE, width=200, height=HEIGHT)
        file_bar.pack(fill="y", side="left")

        # File bar buttons
        file_bar_buttons = tk.Frame(file_bar, bg=OXFORD_BLUE, width=200, height=HEIGHT)
        file_bar_buttons.pack(fill="y", side="left")
        for file in os.listdir(PRJ_DIR + "/graphs"):
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                file_bar_button = tk.Button(file_bar_buttons, text=file,background=RED, fg=SILVER, font=("Arial", 20), width=10, height=2)
                file_bar_button.pack(pady=5)

        self.window.mainloop()


Window()
```

Comment: AFAIK on Mac there is no backgroundcolor for Buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `from tkmacosx import Button`