# tkinter Button in main menu sometimes not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I got the problem when I click a button in my main screen. Sometimes when I click, it works and new window appear, sometime it does not (I can not click). I encounter this problem when trying to run other tkinter programs as well. I got no error when running this code.

My laptop is Mac Pro M1. MyOS is MacOS Sonoma 14.1.1 (Arm Architecture). My Python version is Python 3.9.13

I have test this code on my other laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.10.12 and it ran smoothly.

Here are my source code:

```
import tkinter as tk

# Define the main screen
main_screen = tk.Tk()
main_screen.title("Book Lessons")
main_screen.geometry("500x250")

# Define function to open second screen with lesson content


def open_lesson_screen(lesson_number):
    second_screen = tk.Toplevel(main_screen)
    second_screen.title(f"Lesson {lesson_number}")
    second_screen.geometry("400x200")

    # Add text widget with lesson content
    lesson_content = tk.Text(second_screen, height=10, width=50)
    lesson_content.insert(tk.INSERT, f"This is the content for Lesson {lesson_number}.")
    lesson_content.pack()

    # Add button to close second screen
    close_button = tk.Button(second_screen, text="Close", command=second_screen.destroy)
    close_button.pack()

# Create buttons for 12 lessons


for i in range(1, 13):
    button_text = f"Lesson {i}"
    button = tk.Button(main_screen, text=button_text, command=lambda n=i: open_lesson_screen(n))
    button.grid(row=(i - 1) // 4, column=(i - 1) % 4)

# Start the main loop
main_screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when the button does not work? If so, pls add the error to your question.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75384509/background-button-color-is-not-working-properly-macos/75386173#75386173

Comment: @Dinux I have edited my question. I don't get any error when the button does not work.

Comment: @toyotaSupra No, I installed the package and changed tk.Button to tkmacosx.Button. The button looked nicer but the the problem persists. 70% of the times it worked properly but sometimes it took me 4 to 5 clicks.

Comment: What if you remove parameter ... `tk.Toplevel()`?

Comment: May be the window is open under other window, so it is not visible.  Try adding `second_screen.transient(main_screen)` to make the screen a transient window of the main screen so that it is always on top of the main screen.

Comment: @acw1668 I added the code. The problem still persists. I try multiple python version and found that the problem appear from python3.8 onward. It does not happened in 3.7.6rc1. The GUI looked completely different between python3.7 and the other versions (other version has dark mode and bigger button). All the python version use tk 8.6.

Comment: I try other tkinter code and it works smoothly with python 3.7. The same problem appears with python3.8 onward. Only in MacOS, Ubuntu works smoothly. So for now I guess I just use version3.7 on MacOS.

Comment: How old is your laptop? Why not try Python 3.12.0rc3?

Comment: @toyotaSupra my laptop is mac pro m1 and it about 2 years old. I test with Python3.12.0rc3 (installed via website) and 3.12.0 (through homebrew) and both works smoothly. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update python env to python 3.12.0 resolve my problem.

```
brew install python@3.12
brew install python-tk@3.12
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.12 Application.py
```

Comment: Please add the link from `homebrew`.

Comment: @toyotaSupra i have added the link