# Switching between screens in tkinter results in blank screen

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create a simple GUI with just a couple of buttons, some text and images. However I have 3 screens, one main menu, one for selecting 'actors' and one for 'movies'. When I change from the main menu to 'screen1' it works fine, but when i change from 'screen1' to 'screen2' it is blank. Here is the code, but I use code from other files as well, so if you further information is needed i can upload that as well:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from retrieve_data import movies
from search import search_full_name, search_image

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Whatch: What to watch?")
        self.root.geometry("1000x600")
        self.root.minsize(1000, 600)

        self.main_text = tk.Label(root, text="Whatch: What to watch?", font="Helvetica 40 bold")
        self.side_text = tk.Label(root, text="Ready to find a movie recommendation?", font="Helvetica 20")
        self.main_text.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor="center")
        self.side_text.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.375, anchor="center")

        self.loadimage = tk.PhotoImage(file="gui/startbutton.png")
        self.startbutton = tk.Button(root, image=self.loadimage, command=self.show_screen1)
        self.startbutton["bg"] = "white"
        self.startbutton["border"] = "0"
        self.startbutton.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor="center")

        self.screen1 = tk.Toplevel(root)
        self.screen1.geometry("1000x600")
        self.screen1.title("Your selection: Actors")
        self.screen1.withdraw()

        self.screen2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
        self.screen2.geometry("1000x600")
        self.screen2.title("Your selection: Movies")
        self.screen2.withdraw()

        self.actor_var = tk.IntVar()
        self.movie_var = tk.IntVar()

        liked_actors = []
        while len(liked_actors) < 3:
            movie = random.choice(movies)
            while len(movie['cast']) == 0:
                movie = random.choice(movies)

            actor = random.choice(movie['cast'])
            actor_fn = search_full_name(actor)
            q = tk.Label(self.screen1, text=f"Do you like {actor_fn}", font="Helvetica 40 bold")
            q.pack()

            loadimage_yes = tk.PhotoImage(file="gui/yes.png")
            yesbutton = tk.Button(self.screen1, image=loadimage_yes, command=lambda: self.actor_var.set(1))
            yesbutton["bg"] = "white"
            yesbutton["border"] = "0"
            yesbutton.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.6, anchor="center")

            loadimage_no = tk.PhotoImage(file="gui/no.png")
            nobutton = tk.Button(self.screen1, image=loadimage_no, command=lambda: self.actor_var.set(0))
            nobutton["bg"] = "white"
            nobutton["border"] = "0"
            nobutton.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.6, anchor="center")

            self.screen1.wait_variable(self.actor_var)

            if self.actor_var.get() == 1:
                liked_actors.append(actor)
            q.destroy()

        self.hide_screen1()

        liked_genres = []
        genre_count = 0
        while len(liked_genres) <= 5 and genre_count <= 3 and len(set(liked_genres)) < len(liked_genres):
            movie = random.choice(movies)
            while len(movie['genre']) == 0:
                movie = random.choice(movies)

            q = tk.Label(self.screen2, text=f"Do you like {movie['title']}?", font="Helvetica 40 bold")
            q.pack()

            loadimage_yes = tk.PhotoImage(file="gui/yes.png")
            yesbutton = tk.Button(self.screen2, image=loadimage_yes, command=lambda: self.movie_var.set(1))
            yesbutton["bg"] = "white"
            yesbutton["border"] = "0"
            yesbutton.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.6, anchor="center")

            loadimage_no = tk.PhotoImage(file="gui/no.png")
            nobutton = tk.Button(self.screen2, image=loadimage_no, command=lambda: self.movie_var.set(0))
            nobutton["bg"] = "white"
            nobutton["border"] = "0"
            nobutton.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.6, anchor="center")

            self.screen2.wait_variable(self.movie_var)

            if self.movie_var.get() == 1:
                for genre in movie['genre']:
                    liked_genres.append(genre)
            genre_count += 1
            q.destroy()

    def show_screen1(self):
        self.root.withdraw()
        self.screen1.deiconify()

    def hide_screen1(self):
        self.screen1.withdraw()
        self.screen2.deiconify()

    def hide_screen2(self):
        self.screen2.withdraw()
        self.root.deiconify()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Any help on why the screen2 is blank could help me out greatly.

Comment: It worked for me. Even, If I comment out  `#from retrieve_data import movies`  and `#from search import search_full_name, search_image`.

Comment: really? so it is my system that is not working probably?

Comment: Here is images. https://imgur.com/a/1FDAdp4

Comment: I don't have  this from retrieve_data import movies

Comment: Are you using Macos machine, etc?

Comment: I am using macos, on the images what happens after you click the left button a couple of times (on the your selection actors)? Does it send you to the following screen?

Comment: your problem can be solved. Here is link https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/

Comment: Yes I clicked several  times. You also need `q.configure(text=f"Do you like {movie['title']}?")`

Comment: Here is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77620110/tkinter-button-in-main-menu-sometimes-not-working?noredirect=1#comment136843140_77620110

Comment: sorry to bother you but could you show me an image of the your selection movies screen? and where should i put the q.configure?

Comment: I can't import movies

Comment: here is a small sample of 5 movies:
https://appp.me/HgUVXC so you can remove the import and just add this line of code

Comment: I meant   something like this   py - m pip install movies

Comment: yes but movies is a list that i import from another file not a module/ package.

Comment: I will try it when I get home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256215/discussion-between-toyota-supra-and-lijpe).

Comment: Yes i am there!

Comment: can you provide reproducible code ?

Answer (score 1):

With this information I have here I'd look into the while loops you have in your code which could be blocking the main loops, as well as their conditionals.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).